# Google Sheets scripts ¿Cómo guardar información utilizando ciclo for?

Tags: javascript, script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

He creado un formulario donde puedo registrar los objetivos en una base de datos, funciona correctamente pero el código es muy largo y pienso que podría arreglarlo con un ciclo for, pero no se como usarlo.

el código actual que tengo es:

```
 function Guardar(){



 
  var hojaActiva = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formulario = hojaActiva.getSheetByName("FORMULARIO DE OBJETIVOS"); 
  var datos = hojaActiva.getSheetByName("BBDD"); 

if (formulario.getRange("F16").getValue() ==  'SI') {

if (formulario.getRange("G4").getValue() > 0) 
{
  // Celdas de donde se obtendrán los datos a guardar
  var valores = [[formulario.getRange("B4").getValue(), 
                 formulario.getRange("B5").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("B6").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("D4").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("E4").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("G4").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("H4").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("I4").getValue(), formulario.getRange("J4").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("B8").getValue(),formulario.getRange("B9").getValue()]];
                 
                 
  datos.getRange(datos.getLastRow()+1,1,1,11).setValues(valores); }


if (formulario.getRange("G5").getValue() > 0) 
{
  // Celdas de donde se obtendrán los datos a guardar
  var valores = [[formulario.getRange("B4").getValue(), 
                 formulario.getRange("B5").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("B6").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("D5").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("E5").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("G5").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("H5").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("I5").getValue(), formulario.getRange("J5").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("B8").getValue(),formulario.getRange("B9").getValue()]];
                 
                 
  datos.getRange(datos.getLastRow()+1,1,1,11).setValues(valores); }



if (formulario.getRange("G6").getValue() > 0) 
{
  // Celdas de donde se obtendrán los datos a guardar
  var valores = [[formulario.getRange("B4").getValue(), 
                 formulario.getRange("B5").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("B6").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("D6").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("E6").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("G6").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("H6").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("I6").getValue(), formulario.getRange("J6").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("B8").getValue(),formulario.getRange("B9").getValue()]];
                 
                 
  datos.getRange(datos.getLastRow()+1,1,1,11).setValues(valores); }


  if (formulario.getRange("G7").getValue() > 0) 
{
  // Celdas de donde se obtendrán los datos a guardar
  var valores = [[formulario.getRange("B4").getValue(), 
                 formulario.getRange("B5").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("B6").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("D7").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("E7").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("G7").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("H7").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("I7").getValue(), formulario.getRange("J7").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("B8").getValue(),formulario.getRange("B9").getValue()]];
                 
                 
  datos.getRange(datos.getLastRow()+1,1,1,11).setValues(valores); }


if (formulario.getRange("G8").getValue() > 0) 
{
  // Celdas de donde se obtendrán los datos a guardar
  var valores = [[formulario.getRange("B4").getValue(), 
                 formulario.getRange("B5").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("B6").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("D8").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("E8").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("G8").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("H8").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("I8").getValue(), formulario.getRange("J8").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("B8").getValue(),formulario.getRange("B9").getValue()]];
                 
                 
  datos.getRange(datos.getLastRow()+1,1,1,11).setValues(valores); }


if (formulario.getRange("G9").getValue() > 0) 
{
  // Celdas de donde se obtendrán los datos a guardar
  var valores = [[formulario.getRange("B4").getValue(), 
                 formulario.getRange("B5").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("B6").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("D9").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("E9").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("G9").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("H9").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("I9").getValue(), formulario.getRange("J9").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("B8").getValue(),formulario.getRange("B9").getValue()]];
                 
                 
  datos.getRange(datos.getLastRow()+1,1,1,11).setValues(valores); }

  if (formulario.getRange("G10").getValue() > 0) 
{
  // Celdas de donde se obtendrán los datos a guardar
  var valores = [[formulario.getRange("B4").getValue(), 
                 formulario.getRange("B5").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("B6").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("D10").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("E10").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("G10").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("H10").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("I10").getValue(), 
                 formulario.getRange("J10").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("B8").getValue(),formulario.getRange("B9").getValue()]];
                 
                 
  datos.getRange(datos.getLastRow()+1,1,1,11).setValues(valores); }


  if (formulario.getRange("G11").getValue() > 0) 
{
  // Celdas de donde se obtendrán los datos a guardar
  var valores = [[formulario.getRange("B4").getValue(), 
                 formulario.getRange("B5").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("B6").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("D11").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("E11").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("G11").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("H11").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("I11").getValue(), 
                 formulario.getRange("J11").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("B8").getValue(),formulario.getRange("B9").getValue()]];
                 
                 
  datos.getRange(datos.getLastRow()+1,1,1,11).setValues(valores); }


  if (formulario.getRange("G12").getValue() > 0) 
{
  // Celdas de donde se obtendrán los datos a guardar
  var valores = [[formulario.getRange("B4").getValue(), 
                 formulario.getRange("B5").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("B6").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("D12").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("E12").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("G12").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("H12").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("I12").getValue(), 
                 formulario.getRange("J12").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("B8").getValue(),formulario.getRange("B9").getValue()]];
                 
                 
  datos.getRange(datos.getLastRow()+1,1,1,11).setValues(valores); }


  if (formulario.getRange("G13").getValue() > 0) 
{
  // Celdas de donde se obtendrán los datos a guardar
  var valores = [[formulario.getRange("B4").getValue(), 
                 formulario.getRange("B5").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("B6").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("D13").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("E13").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("G13").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("H13").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("I13").getValue(), 
                 formulario.getRange("J13").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("B8").getValue(),formulario.getRange("B9").getValue()]];
                 
                 
  datos.getRange(datos.getLastRow()+1,1,1,11).setValues(valores); }


  Limpiar(); // Ejecución de función para limpieza de celdas 
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Se ha registrado con éxito');
  }
  else {
     SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('No se ha realizado el check en la casilla de seguridad');
  } 
 }
```

esto del G6 al G13...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así quedaría la BBDD (he ocultado el nombre de los proyectos por tema de protección de datos)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La función del formulario es registrar de forma fija los valores año, mes y proyecto y luego POR CADA LINEA registar los inputs que aparecen en el formulario.

Me gustaría tener un ciclo "for" para cada linea que debo registrar que en este caso sería desde la linea 4 hasta la linea 13.

Así se vería el formulario antes de presionar el boton de registrar: Al presionar el boton desaparecen del formulario y se van a la BBDD que he mostrado anteriormente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es el que digo, proximamente tendré un proyecto donde no serán registar 10 lineas sino que serán mucho más y sin un ciclo for, no lo veo viable.

GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿Depuraste si en `valores` hay datos?

Comment: El "problema" es que repito ese código que ves dos veces, unas 7/8 veces, me gustaría intentar hacerlo usando un ciclo for para evitar esto.

Comment: No entiendo. Tienes una función llamada `Guardar()`. ¿El problema es que la llamas varias veces o el problema es que repites varias veces algo dentro de `Guardar()`? ¿Qué es lo que repites? ¿Qué es lo que define el número de veces que se debe repetir?

Comment: He copiado el código completo en el enunciado para que puedas ver que es lo que digo. El problema es que repito el mismo codigo una y otra vez cambiando tan solo un numero en cada celda por eso me gustaría poder saber aplicar un ciclo for para este caso.

Comment: Aún no aclaras qué es lo que quieres evitar repetir, ¿te refieres a esto? `var valores = [[formulario.getRange("B4").getValue(), 
                 formulario.getRange("B5").getValue(), ...`

Comment: Esto y todas las que van incrementando de uno en uno:
`formulario.getRange("D4").getValue(),
 formulario.getRange("E4").getValue(),
  formulario.getRange("G4").getValue()`
luego
`formulario.getRange("D5").getValue(),
 formulario.getRange("E5").getValue(),
  formulario.getRange("G5").getValue()`
Luego
`formulario.getRange("D6").getValue(),
 formulario.getRange("E6").getValue(),
  formulario.getRange("G6").getValue()`

y así hasta el fin del codigo. Mi duda es si se puede poner un ciclo for en lugar de tener N trozos de codigos iguales que van incrementando de uno en uno

Comment: Siempre es posible simplificar, pero si no entendemos la lógica de tu programa poco podemos ayudarte. Ya, adivinando y preguntando y preguntando se logra entender con dificultad lo que quieres. Convendría que te sientes, te tomes un respiro y luego **definas la lógica de tu programa** y la expongas en la pregunta. No es algo demasiado difícil lo que quieres, el problema es que no entendemos el contexto. Por decir algo, siempre **adivinando**, se aprecia que: las celdas `B4` a `B6` son fijas, las celdas `D` a `I` deben adoptar el valor actual y la celda `B8` es fija ...

Comment: No sé si me explico... intento definir una lógica, una regla de negocio, verbalizar el problema. Pero no es algo que deba hacer yo, sino tú, que es quien está escribiendo este código. Nosotros, para ayudarte **necesitamos comprender**. Si explicas las cosas con claridad la ayuda llegará antes.

Comment: He modificado la descripción añadiendo más detalles. Si necesitas que comparta el documento puedo hacer una copia sin información confidencial. Muchas gracias por las respuestas!

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar una función que reciba los números de casilla y esta devolver el array con los valores de dichas casillas.

```
function añadirValores(casillas){
   const valores = casillas.map(valor => {
      formulario.getRange(valor).getValue()
   }

   return valores;
}

añadirValores("B4","B5", "B6",.....)
```